# How to add / remove classes NativeScript

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

I am trying to dim the opacity of my StackLayout when calling my API via Ajax.

My page is pretty simple:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page"
    xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <ActionBar title="Settings" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout id="layout" >
            <Image src="~/images/header-logo.jpg" stretch="fit" />
            <GridLayout rows="auto, auto">

                <Label
                    text="Hey Welcome! You need to come up with a username. You only have to do this once."  row="0" textWrap="true" class="labelMessage" />
                <TextField id="username" text="{{ username }}"
                    hint="Any username you want" 
                    returnPress="doneTap" autocorrect="false"
                    autocapitalizationType="none" row="1" />

                <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ authenticating }}" />
            </GridLayout>
            <Button text="Save Username" id="registerButton"
                tap="{{ register }}" returnKeyType="done" class="button" />


        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

**Here is a snippet of my View Model...**

```
register: function () {

    if (this.username == null || this.username.length < 4) {
        alert("Come on, enter a username with at least 4 letters!");
        return;
    }

    this.authenticating = true;
```

I have this CSS to modify the opacity:

```
.dimPage {

   opacity: 0.3;

}
```

** My FAILED ATTEMPTS **
Now, I need to figure out how to add and remove that class from my JavaScript. I tried the following approach:

**settings-page.js**

```
var frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");

var SettingsViewModel = require("./settings-view-model");
var settingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();

var pgStackLayout;
var txtUsername;


function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var pgStackLayout = null;

    pgStackLayout = page.getViewById("layout");

    page.bindingContext = settingsViewModel;
}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

**and my settings-viewmodel.js**

```
(snippet when dimming)
pgStackLayout.className = "dimPage";

(snippet when back to full opacity)
pgStackLayout.className = "";
```

I was getting an error saying pgStackLayout is undefined.

Can anyone help me to simply add and remove a class on my StackLayout so I can dim the opacity when an Ajax call is in progress?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on the error description, the variable is simply undefined. You must share at least how you are initialising the variable within your settings model.

Answer (score -1):

> After immersing myself in the DOCS and practicing in the PlayGround...
>   **Resolved**

I took a slightly different approach to achieve my desired results. The following approach , apparently, is quite common - as I have noticed this pattern repeatedly while researching this issue.

So for future readers who are looking to manipulate classes in the core NativeScript application, this worked for me.

**Re-Stating My Initial Problem**
I needed to add ( and remove ) a class to a specific element on my page at a specific time. This needed to be done within my JavaScript (or viewmodel).

Specifically, I want to dim a particular StackLayout's opacity when a particular element  was clicked.

**My Solution**
I am sure there are a hundred ways to do this, but as a beginner NS Developer, I found this simple approach:

```
// [ ... snippet from within my view model code ]
//
// Process The Tap Event
topTap: function (args) {
      const tLabel = args.object; // get a reference to the Label tapped
      elStack = tLabel.parent; // find the parent element of Label, which is the
                               // StackLayout we need.

      elStack.className = "dimPage";  // simply add an existing CSS class
    },
```

to restore opacity to the element, I simple used a blank string:

```
     elStack.className = "";  // remove the above added class name
```

**The ID approach - as alternative**
Once I figured out how to get a handle to the parent element, I then was able to find ANY element using its ID:

```
... [ modifying the snippet above slightly ]

      // Let's assume our StackLayout looks something like this in our XML...
      <StackLayout id="MyStackLayout" height="100%" row="1">

      // To find el's by ID, we need to include the view module first
      const view = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view");

      topTap: function (args) {
          const tLabel = args.object; // handle to tapped element
          parent = tLabel.parent;     // get reference to parent again
          if(parent) {                // make sure we got parent
              let myStack = view.getViewById(parent, "MyStackLayout");   // get view
              myStack.className = "dimPage";   // add class
          }

    },
```

**Dynamically Adding CSS at Page Level**
I also found out I can add CSS rules at the Page level by simply passing a string:

```
// This would immediately dim the StackLayout(s) opacity
page.addCss("StackLayout {opacity: 0.3}");

// ...to restore
page.addCss("StackLayout {opacity: 1.0}");
```

> Closing Thoughts On This...
>   I quickly learned that in NativeScript, I needed to learn the fundamental concept of obtaining a view's handle ( referencing it within your code ).

Once you do that, manipulating elements on the Page is *quite simple*.

A common approach I noticed, to obtaining a handle to the page, is by assigning it to a global variable ***when the page loads***:

```
var _page;     // Our "Global" page variable available to the entire script

function pageLoaded(args) {
  _page = args.object;

}
```

Well, that about covers all needed to know about dynamic classes in my Page. Please remember, the content in this post is from a very new NativeScript developer, so I apologize if this concepts seem extremely basic and at beginner's level. I just thought I would share my journey of learning with other newbies.

Until next time...

John